# Gradle download dependency error

Tags: maven, build, gradle

I'm trying to add the following dependency:

```
compile group: 'com.cedarsoft.commons', name:'test-utils', version:'5.0.9'
```

Gradle downloads a couple of jars and then I'm getting the following error:

```
POM relocation to an other version number is not fully supported in Gradle : xml-apis#xml-apis;2.0.2   relocated to xml-apis#xml-apis;1.0.b2.
Please update your dependency to directly use the correct version 'xml-apis#xml-apis;1.0.b2'.
Resolution will only pick dependencies of the relocated element.  Artifacts and other metadata will    be ignored.
```

Any ideas why and how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 21):

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01'
    }
}
```

Or use 1.0.b2. The issue is that there POM of xml-apis redirects for 2.0.2 (as khmarbaise wrote) to the same group and artefact, only version being 1.0.b2, which somehow fools Gradle (or underlying Ivy) resolution mechanism.

The credit goes to Mark Petrovic [Gradle Forum](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/oddity_in_the_output_of_dependencyinsight_task?utm_content=reply_link&utm_medium=email&utm_source=reply_notification#reply_13104153)

Comment: The gradle forum link is broken at this point :(

Answer (score 8):

If you take a look at the artifact in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22xml-apis%22%20AND%20a%3a%22xml-apis%22%20AND%20v%3a%222.0.2%22) and download the pom file you will get this:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
  <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2</version>
  <distributionManagement>
  <relocation>
    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.b2</version>
  </relocation>
  </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

This means the artifact can be found under the [new coordinates](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22xml-apis%22%20AND%20a%3a%22xml-apis%22%20AND%20v%3a%221.0.b2%22) which means you need to use the new coordinates to use that artiact. I assume you didn't use that artifact directly only via a transitive dependency. This means you need to override the transitive dependency with the new artifact coordinates.