# Migration from Maven to Gradle Causes Unexpected Exception

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle, testng

Moving a TestNG project done in java from maven .pom files to a gradle build.gradle. I was able to get most of the stuff working, but I'm getting an error when running the tests.

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [ApplicationBeans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
```

I am using the spring framework in the test framework code.

Using the following gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
  compile project(':qa_common')
    testCompile(group: 'org.uncommons', name: 'reportng', version:'1.1.4') {
        exclude(module: 'testng')
    }
    testCompile group: 'com.google.inject', name: 'guice', version:'3.0'
    compile group: 'xml-apis', name: 'xml-apis', version:'1.4.01'

}

task testDiscounts(type: Test) {
    useTestNG() {
        suites 'src/test/resources/testsuites/env_qa/TestSuite.xml'
    }

}

task packageTests(type: Jar) {
  from sourceSets.test.output
  classifier = 'tests'
}
artifacts.archives packageTests
```

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: The error seems to hint that `xml-apis` is not in the classpath, but you're build file has this dependency. Can you try setting the classpath of your `testDiscounts` task manually like: `classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath` and see if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if the following is relevant: [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613596/gradle-download-dependency-error/23870656#23870656) .

It might be interesting to force the artifact downloads again and see in the details whether it actually gets version 1.4.01, or whether it redirects it to a different version.

Comment: Forcing it to download it again fixed it.